# How does Highchart's performanace depends on the axis and legend for same numer of points?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am plotting a highchart based chart. I have 3 attributes: salary, person phone number  (cardinality 1000) and person's state (cardinality 10).

Y Axis: Salary, 
Every Legend: Different Color

So here is the problem: 
When I have phone number as X axis and state as legend, the charts renders almost immediately. But when I have state as x-axis and phone number as legend (all with unique color), the chart takes around 10 sec and entire browser freezes till then (Chrome).

I was wondering what's the reason for this? Is this expected behavior? If yes, what's the reason? If not, what can I do in Javascript/otherwise to address this issue?

EDIT:

I also tried disabling animation as per Highcharts recommendations. This did not have any effect.

Comment: Is it trying to create a legend with 1000 elements in it? That'd certainly explain the delay.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate why this is so? What is it doing internally? Also is the expected delay less or is it 10-12 sec?

Comment: Wait, so you have 1000 phone numbers...as series items. that is 1000 series. You want to show 1000 items in the legend. It has to render 1000 series, 1000 color iterations, and 1000 legend items. Is this really necessary?

Comment: So the input depends on the user. I can try other alternatives like Google chart, etc but just wanted to know if there is some optimization/flags I can set within Highchart

Comment: Optimization flags are not avaialvle, but generllay i would take care about correct data, not 1000 series / 1000 points.